# Shiny auto-update table or plot with invalidateLater()

Tags: r, plot, shiny, auto-update

I'd like to understand why the following table is not automatically updated when using `invalidateLater()` inside of an `observeEvent()`. I've prepared the following program to illustrate my question, "mytable2" uses `reactiveTimer()` and does yield the desired output, however "mytable" uses `invalidateLater()` and does not auto-update unless I click the "update" button. Why?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("update", "Update")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      column(6, tableOutput('mytable')),
      column(6, tableOutput('mytable2'))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  values <- reactiveValues(df   = RenderMyTable())

  observeEvent(invalidateLater(1000), {
    values$df <- RenderMyTable()  # This does not update after 1 sec
  })

  observeEvent(input$update, {
    values$df <- RenderMyTable()  # This does update upon clicking
  })

  output$mytable  <- renderTable(values$df)  # Depends on reactiveValues

  autoInvalidate <- reactiveTimer(1000)

  output$mytable2 <- renderTable({
    autoInvalidate()
    RenderMyTable()  # >This does update after 1 sec
  })
}

time1 <- Sys.time()  # Start time
df <- data.frame(a = 1:1000)  # Some data

RenderMyTable <- function(){
  # Seconds since start time
  time2 <- as.integer(difftime(Sys.time(), time1, units="secs"))

  df.now <- df[1:time2,]  # Updates each second

  df.now
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Follow up question**

Also, what would be the appropriate way to get a plot to auto-update (as with "mytable2")? So far, the only way I get a plot to update is by using an "update" button as in "mytable" above, but I'd like it to auto-update after 1 sec since every second new data is begin added to the plot data table.

Any advice or resources you can share is appreciated.

Comment: why dont you make `RenderMyTable()` a reactive function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, I would like to say that I have learnt something from this code, this is a very neat way of automating plot changes, so thank you and I will be using this in future.

To your question, I have looked into `invalidateLater`, which works off of reactive and observation functions, as you have worked towards. Simply changing to `observe` from `observeEvent` and moving the `invalidateLater` function into the main block of the code, rather than passing it as a parameter, fixes this issue on the first table output.

Here is a link of a working version that I took the idea from:
[Shiny - invalidateLater](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/invalidateLater.html)

For your follow up question, we can do this simply through the exact same process as before:

```
output$autoupdate_plot <- renderPlot({

    invalidateLater(2000)
    hist(rnorm(isolate(RenderMyTable())))

  })
```

This will now wait 2 seconds before running the function again. We use `isolate` to avoid updates when values have changed, but update only when we decide, in this case on the 2 second intervals.

Full code below as an extension of your very innovative work:

**app.R**

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("update", "Update")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      column(4, tableOutput('mytable')),
      column(4, tableOutput('mytable2')),
      column(4, plotOutput("autoupdate_plot"))
    )


  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  values <- reactiveValues(df = RenderMyTable())

  observe({
    invalidateLater(1000)
    values$df <- RenderMyTable()  # This does not update after 1 sec
  })

  observeEvent(input$update, {
    values$df <- RenderMyTable()  # This does update upon clicking
  })

  output$mytable  <- renderTable(values$df)  # Depends on reactiveValues

  autoInvalidate <- reactiveTimer(1000)

  output$mytable2 <- renderTable({
    autoInvalidate()
    RenderMyTable()  # >This does update after 1 sec
  })

  output$autoupdate_plot <- renderPlot({

    invalidateLater(2000)
    hist(rnorm(isolate(RenderMyTable())), main = "Auto Hist")

  })
}

time1 <- Sys.time()  # Start time
df <- data.frame(a = 1:1000)  # Some data

RenderMyTable <- function(){
  # Seconds since start time
  time2 <- as.integer(difftime(Sys.time(), time1, units="secs"))

  df.now <- df[1:time2,]  # Updates each second

  df.now
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```